# Nrwl Nx admin page on the same server instance

Tags: angular, nrwl

I hope I can make my question clear.

Actually, we have a monorepo in nrwl with 2 applications. **client** and **client-admin**.

How can I deploy those two applications to the same server but with different routes?

**client-app** should be in the root, i.e http://mypage.com

**client-app-admin** should be in the root, i.e http://mypage.com/admin

Without using Nrwl I would just configure a route and then load my admin component.

Am I over-complicating things?

Answer (score 1):

NRWL is just an workspace for development once its build is an plain angular application. We can decide the way we deploy the application.
There are many solution to it.

Approach 1: Without Middle Layer

1. Create one routing application as bootstrap application.
2. Create you application as Libraries as Lazy Loaded and route according to the URL. Handle internal Routing for those application.

Approach 2: With Middle Layer

1. Keep the two application and build as separate application.
2. Use Node.js as Middle Layer and route the application according to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following a little different style in NrWl architecture.

Below are the steps:

1. Create Nrwl monorepo
2. Create new app - **ng g app client-app**
3. Client app is now root app
4. Create client-app-admin lib - **ng g lib client-app-admin**
5. this lib will be loaded as below

http://mypage.com  - default application

http://mypage.com/admin - your admin lib